Why is grease pencil performing so poorly with many keyframes?
Blender becomes very slow when editing or sculpting on a frame in a Grease Pencil object that has many keyframes. This occurs even when Multiframe is disabled, and regardless of the amount of information on the frame being edited.
Scene playback performance is fine. I'm wondering why this happens even though only one frame is being displayed and edited?
For example, moving points in an object with 500 keyframes would display at 2fps. moving points of the same drawing with other keyframes removed displays at over 60fps.
Thank you for your help, this is making animation very painful.
